# Graphite/Influxdb get total value on Grafana

Tags: graphite, influxdb, grafana

I have Grafana 3.0 with InfluxDB and Graphite datasources.

I have a field with size in GigaByte and I need to know the sum of this field in the last 1h.

I tried `summarize()` and `hitcount()` on graphite, but is not the correct result.

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
It was hitcount, but I have some problem with graphite data and the result is not tthe correct. Now I resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For InfluxDB the query would be `SELECT count(GigaByte) FROM yourmeasurement where time > now() - 1h`